# Microsoft Speech API installation

Tags: windows-7, kinect, sapi, winapi

Which version of Speech API is required for Windows 7 and from where i can download it?

I have tried to download, but they said it's part of Windows SDK itself. I have installed it 3 times till now and I didn't see any Speech related info on SDK installation folder. Am i doing something wrong?

Please help me to setup Speech API in my System.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout `sapi.h` in `include` directory in your Windows SDK installation directory. Check [**this**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/speech/archive/2010/04/30/sample-source-code-for-speech-developers-part-2-and-sapi-5-4.aspx) page for more info.